# Deleting from multiple tables using a left join in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering if I can do the following, I have 3 tables that I want to delete data from : Table1, Table2, Table3

There will always be a record in `Table1` and there might or might not be an associated record in `Table2` and `Table3`.

So I thought I could do the following:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Table1, dbo.Table2, dbo.Table3
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table3 t3 ON t3.Id = t1.Id
WHERE t1.Id = @Id;
```

But I get an `Incorrect syntax near ','.` because of the `DELETE FROM dbo.Table1, dbo.Table2, dbo.Table3` line.

The desired results is to have all the data from the 3 tables deleted with the `Where` clause.

I'm not sure how to acomplish this.

Comment: Remove the first 'FROM' clause and try

Comment: SQL Server only allows you to delete from one table at a time.  Perhaps you want cascading foreign key constraints.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed that doesn't work, I tried that

Comment: @GordonLinoff let's say this is quite an old database and db integrity wasn't that thought out of at the time...

Comment: First you need to remove the first from, 2nd SQL Server allow to delete just from one table, 3rd you can use [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause to delete from 3 tables, or even so by `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Afternatively you could implement a `AFTER DELETE` trigger, however, proper foreign keys and cascading deletes are the way to go.

Comment: Three tables, three `DELETE`s. No way around that. Constraints and triggers are just one way of producing the other deletes within the same transaction.

Comment: What about a stored procedure with a begin/commit transaction around 3 separate delete queries?

Answer (score 5):

You can only delete from one table at a time.  Presumably, you want cascading constraints:

```
alter table2 add constraint fk_table2_table1
    foreign key (id) references table1(id)
    on delete cascade;

alter tablee add constraint fk_tablee_table1
    foreign key (id) references table1(id)
    on delete cascade;
```

Foreign keys ensure data integrity.  Cascading constraints mean that when the primary key is deleted, then the corresponding rows in the other tables are also removed.

Comment: Yeah ideally this would work, but due to the size of the database and the importance of the data, currently cascade deleting is not an option.

Comment: @JamieRees: you can always add the constraint `WITH NOCHECK` so it isn't validated for current data -- and drop it afterwards if you don't like the idea of having it stick around afterwards. This makes the size of the current data largely irrelevant. The only sticking points then are out-of-order inserts, if the system uses those, and possible failure if rows are updated that refer to non-existent parent records (which is typically undesirable anyway, and would justify a preceding scrubbing step, or at least a query to see if there are any).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of methods to this. Personally, I would recommend the SP over the trigger; like others I'm not a huge fan of triggers as they can often be a "hidden" entity (far too many times have I been unable to work out why something isn't working to find it it was a trigger I wasn't aware of).

Anyway, there trigger method would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Cascade_Table2_Table3 ON dbo.Table1
AFTER DELETE
AS

    DELETE T2
    FROM Table2 T2
         JOIN deleted d ON t2.Id = d.Id;

    DELETE T3
    FROM Table3 T3
         JOIN deleted d ON t3.Id = d.Id;
GO
```

However, as you're using a single value, then a parametrised Stored Procedure would be far better; and then you `DENY` users from running a `DELETE` on the tables:

```
CREATE PROC Delete_T1T2T3 @ID int AS

    DELETE FROM dbo.Table1
    WHERE ID = @ID;

    DELETE FROM dbo.Table2
    WHERE ID = @ID;

    DELETE FROM dbo.Table3
    WHERE ID = @ID;

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

can you use a trigger on table1?, so you can delete records only from table1 and then let the trigger delete stuff from table2 and table3.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T_deleteT2_t3]
    ON [dbo].[Table1]
    AFTER  DELETE
AS

BEGIN

    delete from table2 where id = select id from deleted
    delete from table3 where id = select id from deleted

END
```

Comment: It's a valid answer, but I personally don't like the use of triggers in this scenario, triggers in general i'm not a fan of due to their 'hidden' nature.

Comment: What if you delete 100 rows from this table?

Comment: @JamieRees How that can be a valid answer while it has `id = select id from deleted`?

Comment: @Sami Its preudocode just to know if the answer could fit him

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using **[`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** clause

```
CREATE TABLE T1( ID INT);
CREATE TABLE T2( ID INT);
CREATE TABLE T3( ID INT);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1), (3);
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (1), (4);

BEGIN TRAN;

 DECLARE @Out TABLE (IDs INT);

 DELETE T1
 OUTPUT DELETED.ID INTO @Out
 FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;

 DELETE T2
 FROM T2 INNER JOIN @Out O ON T2.ID = O.IDs;

 DELETE T3
 FROM T3 INNER JOIN @Out O ON T3.ID = O.IDs;

COMMIT TRAN;

SELECT *
FROM T1;
SELECT *
FROM T2;
SELECT *
FROM T3;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4bbfc76a1e469eb4c91665b2ebe9c788)**

Answer (score 0):

```
**DELETE t1,t2,t3 FROM**
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table3 t3 ON t3.Id = t1.Id
WHERE t1.Id = @Id;
```

Comment: don't add just the code without explaining your answer